# What's the name of this type of a set?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

So I have a set $\{i_1,i_3,i_5\}$. What do we call the following set? Is there a standard name for it?
$\emptyset, \{i_1\}, \{i_1,i_3\}, \{i_1,i_3,i_5\}$.
Note that we do not have $\{i_3,i_5\}$ in it so it is not a power set. It seems like it is a "naturally ordered poset" to me.

Comment: Note that $\emptyset = \{ \}$ and $\{ \emptyset \}$ are different...

Comment: @PaddlingGhost: They are phisomorphic.

Comment: @copper.hat I mean the empty set.

Comment: I have no idea what to make of this question. What are $i_1$ and $i_3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're really starting with an *ordered* set $(S,<)$. That is, if you just started with an arbitrary set with three elements $\{x,5,*\}$, there would be nothing to distinguish $\{x,*\}$ from $\{x,5\}$. It's important that you know $i_1$ comes first, followed by $i_3$, then $i_5$, right?

Then what you've written down is the set of all *downwards-closed* subsets of $S$. In general, given $(S,<)$, you can form $\{X\in\mathcal{P}(S)\mid \text{if }a\in X\text{ and }b<a\text{ then }b\in X\}$.

I'm extrapolating here, since you haven't made your intentions really clear. Does this capture what you had in mind?

Comment: This seems like just what I had in mind but I want to be sure of when you write {b<a} you mean {order(b) < order(a)}, because else how do you compare a set element with another..

Comment: You compare them using the given ordering $<$ on $S$. If you don't start with an ordering on $S$, this doesn't make sense. What do you mean by order(a)?

Comment: Sorry, am not familiar with all notation and terminologies here. What is the meaning of "< on S" ? Perhaps an example would help? Thanks.

Comment: @bissi "$<$ on $S$" just means that $<$ is a relation which orders the elements of $S$ in some way.